# git hub - same account different repository

Tags: github

I have a github account by my employer. I am working on a project single handedly. Now Is it possible that another employee uses the same account but different repository and does not have access to my repository?

Comment: You have the _same account_ that 2 people use to log in. How can github tell that you are different people?

Comment: so this is not possible?

Comment: Are you using the free version of github, or one of the paid plans?

Comment: its paid ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On googling I found that this is possible if I convert my account into an organization account! So, yes this is possible.

https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization/